How to exit timed out SSH session without exiting earlier jumps?
I am aware I can type exit, logout, or hit Ctrl-D to logout normally. None of this works when the server is timed out, but thankfully I can do Enter-~-. to exit the session.
However, this takes me all the way back to my local session and exits all jumps as well. How do I just exit the current ssh session and not previous jumps?

Do you use ssh -J? Or do you daisy-chain sshs? (Some context here.)

Daisy chain. I do SSH to server1, then ssh to server2 from within server1, and so on

Press ~ twice to send a single literal ~ to the remote session.
So if you are three sessions deep, then ~~~. would exit out of the 3rd level 'ssh' (i.e. it makes the 1st ssh client send a ~~. to the second, and from there it becomes ~. to the third).
Alternatively: Use ssh -e ... to specify a different escape character for each level, which wouldn't be interpreted by the other levels.

Thank you! This works great so far, waiting to try it on a timed out connection before I accept the answer.

So this does indeed work if the only timed out server is the last of the daisy chain... if I timed out of one earlier in the chain then of course i can only jump to the one that is farthest along that hasn't timed out. So it works! Thank you.
